# refuse dns configuration from ISP

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, isp

Is it possible to configure a Linux server not to use the dns-servers it receives from the ISP? If it is, how can it be done?

Cheers

AC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add your desired servers to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If your `resolv.conf` is being overwritten by the information your dhcp client is getting from the ISP, there are usually ways to prevent that, but we'd need more info about what linux distro you're running and what dhcp client you're using.

Comment: +1 for recommending Google DNS servers. The world domination plan is proceeding on schedule.

Comment: I didn't intentionally pick google's servers - those two were just the first two public DNS servers I could remember at the time.